# searching in android not working properly in editext from web

Tags: android, search, android-listview, baseadapter

I have made an activity in which there is an EditText. When I enter any letter into that EditText or the text is changed whenever into that EditText i have called an API for searching the products from the webservice,I have tried as below, but problem is that its not working properly,It does not filter the results based on text inside EditText and does not update the List when i change the text inside EditText.
**Main.java**

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity {
    public com.epe.yehki.uc.Menu searchMenu;
    public Header searchHeader;
    public EditText et_serach;
    JSONObject jsonObj;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    Intent in = null;
    String searchUrl;
    int flag;
    public Header header;
    public Menu menu;
    public TextView title;
    Bitmap bitmap;;
    private ProductAdapter productContent;
    private CategoryAdapter categoryContent;
    // PRODUCTS....
    // arrayLists......
    public static ArrayList<String> productArray;
    public static ArrayList<String> categoryArray;

    //

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray subcategories = null;
    JSONArray products = null;
    public String catid;
    public String id;
    public String pid;
    String name;
    ListView lv;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> subcategoryList;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

    // new
    public String proname;
    public String prodesc;
    public String proimg;

    public String proMinOrderQty;
    public String proMinPrice;
    public String proMaxPrice;
    public String proTerms;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        productList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        searchMenu = (com.epe.yehki.uc.Menu) findViewById(R.id.menusearch);
        searchMenu.setSelectedTab(2);
        searchHeader = (Header) findViewById(R.id.headersearch);
        searchHeader.title.setText("Search");
        et_serach = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_serach);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.serch_list);

        et_serach.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s.length() != 0) {
                    // CALL SEARCH API........!!!
                    new GetSearchList().execute();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    // SEARCH API()..!!!
    private class GetSearchList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SearchActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            BackendAPIService sh = new BackendAPIService();
            searchUrl = Const.API_PRODUCT + "?product_name=" + et_serach.getText().toString().trim();
            System.out.println(":::::::::::::::::::SUB URL:::::::::::::::::" + searchUrl);
            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(searchUrl, BackendAPIService.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
            try {
                if (jsonStr != null) {

                    jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    if (jsonObj.has(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_DETAIL)) {
                        System.out.println("::::::::::::::::true::::::::::::::::" + jsonObj.has(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_DETAIL));
                        products = jsonObj.getJSONArray(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_DETAIL);

                        if (products != null && products.length() != 0) {
                            // looping through All Contacts

                            for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                                pid = c.getString(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_ID);
                                System.out.println("::::::::::::::::::PARSING PRODUCT ID:::::::::::::" + pid);
                                String proname = c.getString(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_NAME);
                                String prodesc = c.getString(Const.TAG_LISTING_DESCRIPTION);
                                String proimg = Const.API_HOST + "/" + c.getString(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_IMG);
                                System.out.println("::::::::::::::;products Length:::::::::::" + products.length());
                                System.out.println(":::::::::::::::My Image Url:::::::::::::" + proimg);
                                String proMinOrderQty = c.getString(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_MIN_ORDER_QTY);
                                c.getString(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_MIN_PRICE);
                                c.getString(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_MAX_PRICE);

                                c.getString(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_PAYMENT_TERMS);

                                // for company details..!!!

                                // new Working

                                HashMap<String, String> product = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                product.put(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_ID, pid);
                                product.put(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_NAME, proname);
                                product.put(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_IMG, proimg);
                                product.put(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_MIN_ORDER_QTY, proMinOrderQty);
                                product.put(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION, prodesc);
                                productList.add(product);

                            }
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("::::::::::::::::::got an error::::::::::::");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

            productContent = new ProductAdapter(SearchActivity.this, productList);
            productContent.notifyDataSetChanged();
            lv.setAdapter(productContent);

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Clear the productList every time you make a new request to your search api. Otherwise products will just keep adding to your list for every search.

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
       super.onPreExecute();
       // Showing progress dialog
       productList.clear();
       pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SearchActivity.this);
       pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
       pDialog.setCancelable(false);
       pDialog.show();
   }
   ```
2. You don't need to create new adapters every time you fetch new results. Declare an adapter in onCreate, set that adapter to the listView. Now every time you make a new request, add new products to your productList, and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

   `notifyDataSetChanged()` will automatically refresh the data from the list that was passed to it while initializing.